# Just heard of Jupyter - is it possible to use Javascript and keep it in the cloud?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ijavascript

I heard of Jupyter last night and was using it with Python last night. Looks like a great notebook for coding, something I have been searching for, but I'm unsure if I can use JavaScript with it? It looks like there are npm packages, but I would assume that would then stop me from saving it all in the cloud and having access across multiple machines..?

Answer (score 3):

IJavascript is an npm package that implements a Javascript kernel for the Jupyter notebook (formerly known as IPython notebook). A Jupyter notebook combines the creation of rich-text documents (including equations, graphs and videos) with the execution of code in a number of programming languages (including Javascript). You may find usage instructions and examples at https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript.

Answer (score 3):

I am new to both worlds and tools like Jupyter and [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) come handy. If you are looking for a similar tool which provides rich and powerful interface in the JS world, [ObservableHQ](https://observablehq.com/) is something you can consider. They provide great UX or I'd rather say DX as in Developer Experience.

They have good [documentation](https://observablehq.com/documentation), [tutorials](https://observablehq.com/tutorials), and a [forum](https://observablehq.com/documentation) as well. I have recently started playing around too.

Comment: How would you compare them with Jupyter?

Comment: @Ooker imho ObservableHQ is great, but the JS ecosystem is yet to have something comparable to numpy, pandas etc. So based on what you want to do the answer varied on what is better. If you're only looking for a comparison of features, here's a nice blog on their website - https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observable-for-jupyter-users

Comment: Thanks. How about Google Colab? How is it compared to ObservableHQ?

Comment: @Ooker I haven't used colab as much so I can't share any comparisons reliably.